# Mostrar los registros que no están en tabla 1 pero si en tabla 2 (Oracle)

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo una situación con un Left Join:

En Oracle tengo dos tablas, en una tengo todo un concentrado de datos (esta tablas solo se editara para generar un id, de ahí en fuera no se le hace nada mas) y tengo otra tabla (tabla de trabajo) que contiene todo un universo de datos en la cual debe de haber ciertas transformaciones para que al final esta tabla de trabajo pueda en su totalidad ser casi idéntica a la primer tabla. La situación es que cuando ya tengo el toda la serie de transformaciones completas, tengo que hacer una consulta para saber que registros de la tabla de trabajo no están en la tabla del concentrado de Datos esto por supuesto por medio de un id que se generan para las dos tablas(como se comentó en el principio) la situación parte cuando hago un LEFT JOIN entre estas dos tablas.

```
SELECT count(*)  FROM ttrabajoaseguradoras t1
LEFT JOIN tcore t2
    ON t2.iddental = t1.c38
    AND t2.situacion_derechohabiente = 'EN VIGOR'
        WHERE t2.iddental IS NULL;
```

Este LEFT JOIN muestra un universo de `7294` registros, lo cual yo supongo son los registros que están en la tabla del concentrado de datos y no en la tabla de trabajo. ahora bien solo lo que necesito y me esta complicando el día es ¿Cómo hago para que en vez de mostrar ese universo de `7294` muestre específicamente los que no están en la tabla del concentrado de Datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una condición `not exists`, que es justamente para eso. No me queda muy claro cual de las dos tablas es la de trabajo y cual es el *concentrado* de datos, así que te pongo un ejemplo algo más general:

```
select t.*
  from TablaTrabajo t
 where not exists (select 1 
                     from TablaConcentrado c
                    where c.idTrabajoRelacionado = t.idTrabajo);
```

Si bien es cierto que con un `left join` puedes obtener el resultado, yo prefiero este porque es más fácil de entender –para el humano– que es lo que se quiere conseguir con la consulta (la semántica, no la sintaxis), y yo siempre pienso en el mantenimiento del código.

Comment: De hecho, es lo que se busca con este tipo de consultas. Que pueda ser manipulable al 100%, me sirvió mucho tu respuesta. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Estas contando registros de ttrabajoaseguradoras que no están en tcore. Asegúrate de que c38 es clave única, porque si no puedes tener repetidos.

Si es así, siempre puedes hacer un `COUNT(DISTINCT c38)` para contar los diferentes c38 que no están en tcore. Puedes hacer los dos `COUNT` al mismo tiempo

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) num_registros
        , COUNT(DISTINCT t1.c38) num_c38_distintos
     FROM ttrabajoaseguradoras t1
     LEFT JOIN tcore t2
       ON t2.iddental = t1.c38
      AND t2.situacion_derechohabiente = 'EN VIGOR'
    WHERE t2.iddental IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de usar el `count(*)` coloca `t1.*` de esta manera te va a traer cada registro que no está. Tienes que definir que información de que tabla quieres mostrar esos datos, por ello colocamos `t1.*` si te llega a dar error colocas `ttrabajoaseguradoras.*`